# ES6 modules - named imports with common alias

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, ecmascript-6

If I understand it correctly ES6 module imports do not allow the following:

```
import { background, border, foreground } as colors from "./colors";

use(colors.background);
use(colors.border);
use(colors.foreground);
```

See

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Is there any explanation why?

I like the idea to explicitly list things that I wish to import. So I do not like `import * as colors from "./colors";` because it makes it unclear what it is that I use.

This is on the other hand too verbose to me: `import { background as backgroundColor, border as borderColor, foreground as foregroundColor } from "./colors";`.

Any idea how to be explicit and not unnecessarily verbose?

Comment: I guess the explanation why that is not possible is because the people in the tc39 didn't consider it to be a case that was worth including in the spec. :)

Comment: you could make an intermediary module that renames the exports from your color module. Although that would lead to even more verbosity not less

Comment: As the previous comment says, it could be a use case for re-exporting module. But this depends on what the module is and what it is for. For a module that can't benefit from tree-shaking, `import * as colors` already does the job, doesn't it?